# Clear and Refresh DataGridView on vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, oledbconnection

Im trying to clear DataGridView and then refreshing to show the updated table. But it say 'Cannot clear the list'. Im not using a datasource for the DataGridView in Design view.

I need the clear function because if I don't it keeps duplicating all the data inside of my DataGridView. 1st time I press is ok as its already empty but onwards gives me the message.

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Refreshdata()
End Sub

Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim DA As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim tables As DataTableCollection = DS.Tables
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

Private Sub Refreshdata()
    DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Risk_Register", myConnection)
    DA.Fill(DS, "Risk_Register")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this: `DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()`: you're not *clearing Rows*, you're resetting a DataSource. Set the DataTable as the DataSource of the BindingSource and the BindingsSource as the DataSource of the DataGridView. Remove other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure how I would do this.

Comment: See update. Is it like that?

Comment: Does `Me.SWOTTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabase.SWOT)` fill the DataTable (is `ProjectDatabase.SWOT` a DataTable)? If it does, then `Me.SWOTBindingSource.DataSource = Me.ProjectDatabase.SWOT` and `Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.SWOTBindingSource`. `Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()` is not required, that repaints the UI, nothing to do with the data.

Comment: I added a few images if they help to answer your question. its my first time using DataGridView and have no idea

Comment: What is the problem? Is the DataTable already filled and you get duplicate data? Then clear the DataTable before filling it again. Is the TableAdapter filling the DataTable? It does but the BindingSource doesn't reset the binding? What is not working? What is the object that doesn't provide the expected results? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Iv gone back to my original coding, it refreshes the data every time but also duplicates all the data x2. Every time I press it duplicates all the data, not on my MS access database, only duplicates it on the DataGridView1

Comment: Read again my previous two comments: do that and you're ok. I mentioned the Rows duplication in the DataTable in the second: dispose of the DataTable, create a new one and fill it: no more duplicates. It also probably means that you don't have a Primary Key there.

Comment: Its just i dont really understand how I would code it, im a complete beginner and not really sure how to code this into my app.

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing DS.Reset() [...] DA.Fill(DS, "Risk_Register") source1 = new BindingSource(DS, "Risk_Register") DataGridView1.DataSource = source1`

Comment: what would I have to insert into [...] ?

Comment: Don't you have `DA = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Risk_Register", myConnection)` there?

Comment: Oh yeah I do, can you check update to post to see if its supposed to be like this?

Comment: It could work if the TableAdapter knows what the query and the connection are. Are you setting this somewhere else now? If not, add back the line you removed. -- Note that storing the Connection object as a Field is very bad practice, especially with a MS-Access database. Also, are you actually using the DataSet and the Tableadapter for something, other than handling the DataTable? If you're not, then you should just load the DataTable with a DataReader. -- There are tons of posts that deal with this stuff. Take a look around, you'll find a lot of material.